# Greenshot: Windows title not displayed in file name anymore

Tags: windows-10, updates, filenames, greenshot

`${title}-${capturetime:d"yyyy-MM-dd HH_mm_ss"}-`

This is the file name system that I'm using to name files on greenshot.

The `${title}` promises to name the file with the title of the window being captured.

However, it saves all screenshots starting with 'Greenshot' instead of the windows title for some reason.

Eg. `Greenshot-2019-11-14 14_38_27-`

I can't figure if it's a software or a user issue.

Comment: It's just Window for me at the end, but yeah, this really makes the program unusable garbage for me!

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually doing a window capture? Or fullscreen? The full screen mode currently does not capture any window title. If so, please try a window capture. Read the discussion here for more information: https://greenshot.atlassian.net/plugins/servlet/mobile?originPath=%2Fbrowse%2FBUG-2411#issue/BUG-2411